# summary calculated field through relation

Tags: devexpress, xtrareport

I am trying to sum values that are under a related table i.e.:

`Sum([ServiceLines.Services.total_price])`

But have had no success. I am currently getting the first value of the related table instead of a sum of all the values.

Am I doing this wrong or is this behavior not supported?

Comment: This field shouldn't be in the detail section of the report.

Comment: the field is already there, what i need to know is if i can sum values via a relation or not.

Comment: You can sum values via a relation. Something is going wrong in your case. Add more details to your question.